# Hiding "half" of the New button in the SharePoint ribbon

Tags: javascript, jquery, ribbon

I built a calendar with multiple content types. What I'm basically trying to achieve here is to force a user to choose from those content types when creating a new item instead of defaulting to the one that SharePoint chooses when the New button is clicked. To do this, I would like to hide the **TOP part of the New button**. I've seen plenty of posts on how to hide the content types from the list, but I'm trying to achieve the opposite.

I have figured out using CSS how to hide the button, but this hides the entire thing instead of just the top part of the button. Also, I can disable it, and just use custom built buttons, but I'd rather not do this as I'd have to embed this everywhere a new view is. I've tried a bunch of jQuery and Javascript, but nothing I do seems to help.

The perfect thing to do, I assume would be to use some jQuery or Javascript to unbind the "click" event from the button. I can't seem to figure it out, though.

I have no access to back end (VS, etc.). I cannot change the master page either. I DO, however, have access to master page CSS, so I can manipulate that. This will have to be done either via CSS, jQuery, or Javascript via a CEWP.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The New button should only be showing the content types you defined on your calendar. Are you saying if they click the New button they get the default Event, not one of yours? You can remove that 'Event' content type from the button.

Once you do that, make sure your most used content type is first, so if they click the button without going to the dropdown, they'll get the most common content type.

In List Settings in the browser, in the Content Types section, click on 'Change new button order and default content type'. Make sure only your CTs are selected, and the most common is #1.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

That's the whole point. I already assigned multiple content types to the calendar (list). However, I want the user to be FORCED to choose a content type should they hit the New button,  rather than the user be given the option of choosing the tiny (in comparison) dropdown, which should I note does exactly what I want. 

The premise is that the New button goes to the default content type; fine. But in my case, content types need to be forced on the users who don't really care about integrity of data.